# Python BeautifulSoup to get content from parent/sibling relationship

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Part of a html is structured as below. I want to get the job “title” and “time” from it. I can get them separately, like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


pages = '<div class="content"> \
                <a href="Org"> \
                        <h3 class="title"> \
                            Dep. Manager</h3> \
                        </a> \
                <div class="contributor"></div> \
                <p>John</p> \
                <time class="time"> \
                        <span class="timestamp">May 02 2016</span> \
                    </time> \
                </div>'


soup = BeautifulSoup(pages, "lxml")


soup.prettify()


s = soup.find_all(class_ = "title")[0]

t = soup.find_all('span', class_ = "timestamp")[0].text.strip()


pp_title = s.text.strip()

print t

print (pp_title)
```

It returns me that wanted.

```
Dep. Manager
May 02 2016
```

For the "time", I want another way to get it, as the “time” is always below the “title”. I tried this line to get the “time”, it doesn’t work.

```
print (s.parent.next_sibling.next_sibling)
```

What’s the right way to get the “time” from the relationship to “title”? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `findParent` with specifying details:

```
t = s.findParent("div", class_='content').find('span', class_='timestamp').text.strip()
```

Example:

```
titles = soup.find_all(class_="title")
for title in titles:
    timestamp = title.findParent("div", class_='content').find('span', class_='timestamp').text.strip()
    print(title.text.strip(), timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether the issue lies in the string you are providing or somewhere else, but every other call to `next_sibling` returns `u' '`. So I tried this:

```
s.parent.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.findChildren()[0]
```

I know it's long, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `soup.find_all` with `re`:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
result = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup(pages, 'html.parser').find_all(re.compile('h3|span'), {'class':re.compile('title|timestamp')})]
```

Output:

```
['Dep. Manager', 'May 02 2016']
```

Comment: great way of thinking, also skillful and advance that benefit learners.  hope you don't mind I chose the earlier one for the answer! :)

Comment: @MarkK Not at all, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Select for the shared parent then grab the children by class. Assumes parent always has both. You can change selector to ensure has both if required.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div class="content"> \
    <a href="Org"> \
                        <h3 class="title"> \
                            Dep. Manager</h3> \
                        </a> \
    <div class="contributor"></div> \
    <p>John</p> \
    <time class="time"> \
        <span class="timestamp">May 02 2016</span> \
    </time> \
</div>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
items = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('.content:has(.title) .title, .content:has(.title) .timestamp')]
print(items)
```

Comment: thank you for the sharing. skillful and advanced use of BeautifulSoup parsing! hope you don't mind I chose the earlier one for the answer! :)